# JDBC GUI login, textfield to local string variable

Tags: java, user-interface, jdbc, netbeans

I have a TextField for a username named `username` and a PasswordTextField named `password`. I declared two local string variables, `user` and `pass`. I have a database but I still can't get into the "welcome" part. This is my code.

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    //making a connection through the driver
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login", "root", "123456");
    //System.out.println("Connected to database");
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM login.credentials");

    while (rs.next()) {
        String user = rs.getString("username");
        String pass = rs.getString("password");

        if (username.equals(user) && password.equals(pass)){
            System.out.println("Welcome!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid password!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: what values are there in username 'n password inside if statement? Show stack trace, what error you are facing

Comment: I know my username and password is right but I still can't get into the System.out.println("Welcome");

Comment: it doesn't show any errors
I just know i have input the correct username and password but I still cant login. I think there is a problem with the while loop? or problem that my program cant access the values inside my database well, it can access the database but im still getting "invalid password"

Comment: Add debug statements in your code.
Check if the connection is null or not.
Then also add print statements in while loop and check variables user and pass.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following inside Your servlet code:
`String username = request.getParameter("username");
 String password = request.getParameter("password");` 
then try to compare two String , one (`username`or `password`) which is retrieved from the `TextBox` , nd other(`username` or `password`) which is retrieved from your database using `ResultSet`.
Hope this is works for you..